# Qmail errors using qmailctl

Tags: debian-jessie, qmail

I am following the guide "Life with Qmail  [Life With Qmail](http://lifewithqmail.org/)

When I try to execute the qmailctl command, I get the following:

```
root@mail:~# qmailctl start
Starting qmail
qmail-send supervise not running
qmail-smtpd supervise not running
svok: fatal: unable to chdir to /service/qmail-pop3d: file does not exist
qmail-pop3d supervise not running
root@mail:~# qmailctl stop
Stopping qmail...
qmail-smtpd
qmail-send
qmail-pop3d
svc: warning: unable to chdir to /service/qmail-pop3d: file does not exist
svc: warning: unable to chdir to /service/qmail-pop3d/log: file does not exist

Here is my /service/directory : 

root@mail:~# ls -l /service/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Nov 27 09:49 qmail-pop3d ->   /var/qmail/supervise/qmail-pop3d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Nov 27 09:22 qmail-send ->   /var/qmail/supervise/qmail-send
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Nov 27 09:22 qmail-smtpd ->  /var/qmail/supervise/qmail-smtpd
root@mail:~#

I have found a few links on Gossamer Threads and LinuxQuestions.
I tried a few things, but to no avail.
```

[Gossamer Threads](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/qmail/users/54618)

```
I tried the command  svscanboot, but it hangs.
 then I tried kill -HUP 1

 I tried to find the svscan process to kill it to no avail.
```

- can only post 2 links. I tried this that I found on linuxquetions.org
  when you google the specific error, these two links will be close to the top

  I tried # svscanboot & , but still nothing. Then I rebooted to the same issue.

  what am I missing?

Comment: QMail is dead. Let it rest in peace and choose a modern, maintained MTA.

Comment: Trying to run some legacy software.

Answer (score 0):

I dumped the debian droplet at DO, and loaded Centos 7.2  Maybe it will help someone in the future. There were a few threads about this issue, posted around the internet. I gave up on the "Life With Qmail" plan and reinstalled Qmail using [Qmail Toaster](http://www.qmailtoaster.com/) for Centos. Took about 45 minutes.This toaster re-installed a fresh copy of the scripts, which are now working.